# How to modularize shaders in Processing 3.x

Tags: glsl, processing, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'd like to use the same noise function throughout various `.glsl` files without copying and pasting code every time.
What is the processing way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, there is no way to do this *dynamically* in Processing.  However, you can separately compile your shaders with `glslify`, which is a GLSL compile-time include system.

`glslify` (https://github.com/glslify/glslify) is a bit of overkill, though.  Whenever I make an OpenGL / GLSL application, I roll my own system.
Something like this (taken from my Java OpenGL Minecraft clone [here](https://github.com/mackycheese/GLMinecraft1/blob/master/src/co/megadodo/mc/client/gl/Shader.java#L23-L35)):

```java
    private static String process(String code){
        String[]lines=code.split("\n");
        for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
            if(lines[i].startsWith("#include : ")){
                lines[i]=process(Utils.loadFile("path_to_include_directory/"+lines[i].replace("#include : ","")+".glsl"));
            }
        }
        StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder();
        for(String s:lines){
            str.append(s).append("\n");
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
```

This code does a copy-paste on includes.  Usage:

```c
///// MAIN FILE
#include : bar_module

float foo(vec3 p){
    return bar(p * 5.0);
}
```

```c
///// path_to_include_directory/bar_module.glsl
float bar(vec3 p) {
    /* ... ... */
}
```

This is a recursive includes mechanism, fairly efficient, at runtime.  No static compilation needed!
The only downside is that circular dependencies aren't detected.  But you shouldn't be in a situation with circular dependencies anyway :)

DISCLAIMER
I don't actually remember how this stuff works, but I think this is the general idea:

```
File file=new File("my_shader.vert");
file.setContents(process(file.readContents()));

PShader my_shader=new PShader("my_shader");
```

NOTE: `setContents` and `readContents` don't actually exist, but you get the idea :)

PS
Utils.loadFile returns the contents of the filename passed in as a String.

Comment: I know glslify but never thought to use it like this, i will definetly try your approach